# powermail dynamic receivers based given number

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, powermail

The Task: User Types a number into field "x". The first 3 Digits are used to determine the receiver-mail.

What i have got so far:

```
plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.receiver.predefinedReceiver {
receiverstest.email = CASE
receiverstest.email {
    key.data = GP:tx_powermail_pi1|field|x
    key.stdWrap.crop = 3 | | 0

    001 = TEXT
    001.value = receiver1@mailtest.com

    002 = TEXT
    002.value = receiver2@mailtest.com

    default = TEXT
    default.value = default@mailtest.com
}
```

}

The Problem: Powermail uses always the default mail.
The Questions: What is my error here? How can it work?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe the crop function is not taking effect. Maybe test without cropping and just entering 001 i.e.. Or test a longer number and also add the number in the TS.
If that works you could add a hidden field in the form and crop the Input with a JS function.

Comment: It seems its not working at all. i tried just using 3 digits and its not even using the default mail. it just takes the address from the confirmation mail i put in the plugin settings (it was the same as the default).

Comment: I use the same setup with some small differences and it's working. I don't use the key.stdWrap.crop line. And instead of `receiverstest`i use `receivers1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mystery solved: i forgot to set this in the page TSconfig:

```
tx_powermail.flexForm.predefinedReceivers.addFieldOptions.receiverstest = receivers #1
```

Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Syntax of `crop` is: [numbers of characters to keep] | [ellipsis] | [keep whole words] (-> [TSref: `stdWrap.crop`](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/Functions/Stdwrap.html?#crop))

So, the '1' of the last part of your snippet will keep whole words - exactly what you do *not* want in your case. A word, which would normally be cut in the middle, is removed completely => your TS will always fall in default-case.

Comment: Thanks i corrected the code to 3||0. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Strange... If I put your `CASE` in a test-instance as page-content, the behavior is correct (`https://example.com/` / `https://example.com/?tx_powermail_pi1[field][x]=001abc&no_cache=1`

Comment: A Version issue maybe? I'm using 7.4.3